# Safari iphone simulator debug not working

Tags: xcode

I run Safari on the iOS simulator and then debug it by running mac safari.
Debug is working, but it does not show any elements (elements, network, debugger, resource, canvas, console, everything).

```
xcode version : 10.2 (10E125)

safari version : 12.0.3(14606.4.5)

simulator : ios12.2(all device problem)
```

Please help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the version of macOS and Xcode installed on your Mac? What is the device type and iOS version running in the iOS simulator? Kindly [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55565938/edit) your question and specify.

Comment: Having the same problem. The Safari desktop Develop menu shows the simulator and the tabs open on the simulator's Safari. Selecting a tab does not show any elements, or network traffic.

Comment: I believe this is a bug on any device running iOS 12

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it. 
Download [Safari Technology Preview](https://developer.apple.com/safari/download/) and use that instead of regular Safari.

Via [Apple Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/89455)